# Utilizar BETWEEN junto com IN()

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Gostaria de comparar diversas datas dentro de um intervalo de datas. Tentei realizar a consulta abaixo mas não consigo uma lógica adequadas.

Consulta com *Array + BETWEEN* no Mysql, ou melhor, utilizar a expressa `IN()` junto com `BETWEEN`.

Já tentei algumas formas mas não consegue

1)

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  Conteudo
WHERE
  ('2018-03-22', '2018-03-23') BETWEEN DATE(DataInicio) AND DATE(DataFim)
```

2)

```
SELECT
      *
    FROM
      Conteudo
    WHERE
      BETWEEN DATE(DataInicio) AND DATE(DataFim) IN('2018-03-22','2018-03-23' )
```

Answer (score 2):

É "possível", mas pra fazer isso você precisa isolar as expressões:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Conteudo
WHERE
    campo_data BETWEEN DATE(DataInicio) AND DATE(DataFim) 
    AND campo_data IN('2018-03-22','2018-03-23')
```

Comment: Se existir um campo data, realmente funciona dessa maneira, porém se as datas forem inputadas manualmente, não funcionaria dessa maneira.

Comment: não entendi, @arllondias. Tem que existir um campo de data, caso contrário não vai ter o que checar na base

Comment: Não é necessário mais um campo, pensa que ele já tem os campos que no caso da `query` dele ele informa que tem o `DataInicio` e `DataFim`.
Se ele colocar uma data na mão e deixar assim por exemplo: `WHERE '2018-03-22' BETWEEN DATE(DataInicio) AND DATE(DataFim)` ele vai me trazer os registros onde a data inputada se encaixa entre as datas que ele já tem no banco, entendeu? exatamente como coloquei na minha resposta ali.

Comment: @arllondias, entendi. Sendo assim, a sua resposta está correta :P

Comment: adicionei um exemplo funcional na minha resposta =)

Answer (score 1):

Bom, pelo que eu sei isso não é possível, mas você pode ir adicionando condições OR no seu código ao invés do IN, ai ficaria mais ou menos dessa maneira:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  Conteudo
WHERE
  '2018-03-22' BETWEEN DATE(DataInicio) AND DATE(DataFim)
  OR '2018-03-23' BETWEEN DATE(DataInicio) AND DATE(DataFim)
...
```

Segue exemplo com testes:

```
CREATE TABLE teste_datas(
    descricao VARCHAR(255), 
    data_inicio DATE, 
    data_fim DATE
);

INSERT INTO teste_datas(descricao, data_inicio, data_fim)
VALUES('desc 1', '2018-03-01', '2018-03-22'),
('desc 1', '2018-03-01', '2018-03-23'),
('desc 2', '2018-03-01', '2018-03-24'),
('desc 3', '2018-03-01', '2018-03-08'),
('desc 4', '2018-03-01', '2018-03-02');`
```

Caso eu rode essa `query`:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM teste_datas
WHERE '2018-03-22' BETWEEN data_inicio AND data_fim;
```

O resultado será `desc1, desc2 e desc3` pois a data que estou procurando se encaixa entre os dois periodos

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
SELECT
    *
FROM teste_datas
WHERE '2018-03-22' BETWEEN data_inicio AND data_fim
OR '2018-03-07' BETWEEN data_inicio AND data_fim;
```

se eu adicionar o `OR` a `query` me retornará `desc1, desc2, desc3 e desc4` pois a segunda data também se encaixa a uma linha.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1):

É possível, da forma como segue.

O único porém é se você deseja var um `OR` como no exemplo abaixou ou um `AND`.

```
SELECT * FROM Conteudo
WHERE (campo_data BETWEEN DataInicio AND DataFim)
OR (campo_data in ('2018-03-22','2018-03-23'))
```